# Печать pdf в Angular2

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5, angular-routing

Как принять и распечатать PDF файл в Angular2? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону ng-pdf-make https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pdf-make

На сайте сказано следующее:

> Чтобы использовать функции открытия, загрузки и печати, вы можете переопределить методы...

```
<button (click)="pdfmake.open()">Open PDF</button>
<button (click)="pdfmake.print()">Print PDF</button>
<button (click)="pdfmake.download()">Download PDF</button>
```